# Using three elements condition in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, logic

I have a weird bug.
I have A class names Lessons with 3 elements: video, audio & written.
A functios called IsReadOnly supposed to check if a lesson has something only in the 'written' cell while the 'audio' and the 'video' are empty.
This is how it looks:

```
public function IsReadOnly() {
    if ($this->Audio=="" && $this->Video=="" && $this->WrittenLesson!="")
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

In the PHP page I'm calling the function:

```
if (!$Less->IsReadOnly()) {
    // ...
}
else {
    // ...
}
```

as far as i get - while video/audio will return false, the full condition will return false  also and the IF (not the ELSE) will be executed.

But, thats not working. If the video is empty and the audio isn't - everythig is fine. but if the audio is empty and the video isn't - the ELSE is executed. (I've tried replacing between them, nothing...).

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Is the value an object or resource or array? Maybe you want to use isset() or empty() instead of == ""

Comment: We are going to need to see your [testcase](http://sscce.org)..

Comment: @OIS, the value is always just a text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the solution was to make the SSCCE...
While testing I've found the problem. The video wasn't the only cell I had to check because in the database there were two fields that represent video.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to make the `if` more forgiving:

```
if ($this->WrittenLesson && !$this->Audio && !$this->Video)
```

Comment: AFAIK, this is the same as his statement

Comment: Maybe so. We need to see real examples from the OP.